# Sql Update duplicate

Tags: sql, database, replace, duplicates

I have a serial_no (primary key) and I want replace a word in serial_no. For example:

```
Update table Set 
serial_no=REPLACE(serial_no,'56','000')
```

But receive an error duplicate for update

I want update all records except that record is duplicated

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Knowing your data model would be helpful. Please see [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Use `NOT EXISTS` to make sure the new serial_no doesn't already exist.

```
Update table t1
Set serial_no=REPLACE(serial_no,'56','000')
where not exists (select 1 from table t2
                  where t2.serial_no = REPLACE(t1.serial_no,'56','000'))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL you could use `UPDATE IGNORE`:

```
UPDATE IGNORE table
SET serial_no = REPLACE(serial_no,'56','000')
```